# Clojure Box: classpaths

Tags: clojure, classpath

I'm stuck with "Programming Clojure" on page 37 on a Windows 7
machine. After downloading the "examples" dir into "C:/clojure", I
typed:

```
user> (require 'examples.introduction)
```

and I got

```
; Evaluation aborted.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate examples/
introduction__init.class or examples/introduction.clj on classpath:
(NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

My .emacs file looks like this:

```
(setq swank-clojure-extra-classpaths
           (list "C:/Clojure"))
```

The files in C:/Clojure are there (I triple checked)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you also check your classpath from the REPL: `(System/getProperty "java.class.path")`?

Comment: Can you confirm that clojure is running from the right place?
user> (. System getProperty "user.dir") will print the current directory. Check that that comes up as C:/Clojure

Comment: Thanks for your hints on checking the classpath and the user dir from inside the REPL, guys. Here are the results. The classpath is:

"c:/Program Files/Clojure Box/swank-clojure/src;c:/Program Files/Clojure Box/lib/clojure-contrib.jar;c:/Program Files/Clojure Box/lib/clojure.jar"

and the user dir is:

"c:\\Clojure"

Sorry for my (non-)formatting; unfortunately, I don't know how to format source code in my comments yet.

Comment: I get the error unless I (set! *compile-path* ".")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! The .emacs file should contain this line - watch out for "classpath" without the "s"):

```
(setq swank-clojure-classpath
        (list "c:/Clojure"))
```

Thanks to Shawn Hoover for giving me this answer via email. (And thanks to everybody else for your hints!)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(setq swank-clojure-extra-classpaths ("C:/Clojure"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I did. Didn'T work:

<code>

Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Emacs/.emacs':

Invalid function: C:/Clojure

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

</code>

Comment: Ah. My bad. no parenthesis around the string, it is trying to evaluate it (I'm new at this, too).

(setq swank-clojure-extra-classpaths "C:/Clojure")